Latex not compiling tables correctly in Editorial Manager
I'm trying to submit to an Elsevier journal through the Editorial Manager. The latex file was created in Overleaf. It mostly compiles well, including two tables. The problem is that the tables appear again after the Bibliography on separate pages and one of them is cut in half, so it's actually on two pages. Should they be there at all?

Welcome, could you provide a MWE so people can see the problem and try to fix it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome! What does 'mostly' mean? Do you get errors or warnings?
